# Positioning divs

Tags: html, css

Hi team,

Basically, I am not very good at getting divs to line up side by side and take on equal height as the one beside it (example below).

[image: desired outcome]

I wondered if anyone could help me with coding this. I have placed Areas B and C in their own div and are responding well but I am having issues aligning it to Area A in the picture. This will be an issue when moving the resolution of the screen in the future.

I am currently using HTML and CSS to achieve this outcome. Further, these areas do not have gaps they are connected - only in question picture for clarity.

Regards,

Laura

Comment: Can you add what i've you done ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit more advanced, but you could do it using CSS grid layouts. This would be the CSS assuming each area has a class.

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr; /* right col 3* larger than left col */
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    "area-b area-a"
    "area-c area-a";
}

.area-a {
  grid-area: area-a;
} 

.area-b {
  grid-area: area-b;
} 

.area-c {
  grid-area: area-c;
}
```

Compatibility is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/css-grid/embed

Comment: I was using Explorer and it didn't work but worked in my Chrome and Firefox. Weird. Who uses IE anymore anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Below might be the easiest way:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.area {
  position: absolute;
}

.a {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 75vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
}

.c {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 25vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="area a">A</div>
<div class="area b">B</div>
<div class="area c">C</div>
```

Comment: I enjoyed this one because I feel it matches what I know. However, I didn't know that you can do .area as the start of a div and then .a,.b,.c and additional points. Can you please explain this further?

Comment: Actually, just put in my content: what if there is overflow that is not wanting to be hidden?

Comment: Looks great through. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome! area, a, b, and c are all names of classes. I just attached styles to divs using class names. Regarding making the page scrollable, you need to change the layout a little bit. Google 'clearfix' hack and try it. 'flex' will do the same but its a bit more advanced. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<html>

    <head>  
    <style>
    .left-section{float:left; width:25%;}
    .right-section{float:left; width:75%;}
    .area-left{width:100%; height:50%; background:#e5e5e5; border:2px solid #000;}
    .area-right{border:2px solid #000; width:100%; height:100%; background:#e5e5e5;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="left-section">
        <div class="area-left">
            <span>Area B</span>
        </div>
        <div class="area-left">
            <span>Area C</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-section">
        <div class="area-right">
            <span>Area A</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```